# Generate correct legend with auto.key in xyplot

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I realize this is perhaps more of a data frame issue than a xyplot questions - but here it goes.
I have a data frame dat that has 108 rows and 5 columns. dat$Treatment is a factor with 5 levels. I want to create an xy plot with ONLY the data where dat$Treatment=="Control". Since I didn't know any better way to do it, I created tmp as shown below. xyplot plots the correct graph, with only the data in the rows where dat$Treatment=="Control". However the legend displays all the data, for example those where dat$Treatment=="High dose"

Where is auto.key getting that from? I thought my tmp data frame didn't even have it. Can someone please help me understand?

```
 tmp <- dat[dat$Treatment=="Control",]

xyplot(tmp[,5] ~ Day, groups=tmp$Animal, data=tmp, 
       type="b", ylab="Tumor volume", 
       par.settings=simpleTheme(col=1:8,
                                pch=20,
                                cex=1.3,
                                lwd=2,
                                lty="dotted"),
       auto.key=list(title="Animal", x=.05, y=.95, 
                     corner=c(0,1), border=T, lines=T, points=F, type="b"))
```

Comment: Thank you! That not only worked, but also now I understand how and why. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the lattice package, so others with more experience will have to weigh in.  My guess is that you're seeing this behavior because of how R is handling dat$Treatment.  I'm guessing this variable is stored as a factor, with levels you don't want to include in the plot.  As a rough first step, I'd try saving the new data frame (as you have), but additionally run the following command:

```
tmp$Treatment = as.factor(as.character(tmp$Treatment))
```

This should save the Treatment variable as a factor with only one level.  My guess is that the xyplot function looks up the levels of that factor when it plots.  As a related example, consider the following:

```
data(iris)

iris.2 = iris[iris$Species == "setosa",]
table(iris.2$Species)

iris.2$Species = factor(as.character(iris.2$Species))
table(iris.2$Species)
```

Here, the two tables are reported differently because we've resaved the Species variable as a new factor.  Hope this helps --

Answer (score 0):

auto.key get's its values form the levels of the factor variables. When you subset a factor variable, all the levels are maintained (so in the future, you can know which levels are missing from a particular subset). If you want to remove levels that aren't used in your subset you can use

```
tmp <- droplevels(dat[dat$Treatment=="Control",])
```

This way auto.key will never see the other factor levels.